# Storybook disable javascript

Tags: storybook

We have a server side rendered application that supports both javascript and no javascript versions. It's a simple form and with storybook I'd like for it to test both as the CSS is different for each.

I have done a bit of research on how to do it but the only thing I've come across is putting the content within an iframe with sandbox mode on. The issue with this is then if I want to run the storybook a11y addon it won't work because it needs the axe-core script within the iframe (from my understanding) but this clearly won't execute if there's no javascript enabled.

Am I out of luck with this?

I'd be ok with running a11y only on the JS version if that is an option.